# Layout not adjusting in Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-tablayout

I am working on a app in which layout structure is as follows -

Activity A - This activity is a Tab Layout Activity which uses viewpager for tabs and code is given below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragment that is added to the viewpager has a common layout for all tabs and code is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/background_app"
    tools:context="com.peacecorps.pcsa.safety_tools.SafetyPlanActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/safety_plan_subtitle"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/safety_plan_pager"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/actionButton"
        style="@style/NavigateButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="@string/see_action"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see this fragment again contains a viewpager.This viewpager will always be populated by a fragment below.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/text_to_show"
        layout="@layout/textview"/>
</ScrollView>
```

where textview is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is the common layout used for TextViews-->
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_textview_rounded_rectangle"
        android:padding="@dimen/textview_padding"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:autoLink="web|email"
        android:textColorLink="@color/text_color_link"
    />
```

Here textview contains text of different amount which is set dynamically in java for different tabs.
The problem I am facing is that only part of UI is available in landscape mode and some part is lost which is not scrollable too.Please help me, I am stuck on this for a really long time.

Comment: I know the problem is that there are multiple scrollviews which confuses android safety_plan_pager has fixed height which means it can only take limited text and thus will need scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you have 2 ***scrolling behavior***. When the phone is on ***portrait mode*** it has a lot of space that 320dp height ***ViewPager*** won't be able to occupy all the spaces available, but when the phone is on ***landscape mode*** 320dp height ***ViewPager*** will occupy the whole screen so the layout will only scroll the second view pager, that means that the whole screen on ***landscape mode*** will only have access on the second ***ViewPager***. 
Remember that the ones on the bottom are the first to be accessed. That means that a ***view*** that is on the bottom have a higher ***z-index*** - Code Reference not the actual view.

Comment: Thanks.Now I understood what is happening but how can I solve it. :-)

Comment: I made some adjustments after knowing this problem and it fulfilled my requirement. However I don't know how to solve this problem exactly. If you could answer, it might be helpful to the community. Thanks

Comment: you can solve it by using percentage in your layout. linear layout have an attribute called weightSum and layout_weight on its child. you should read more on that